# Rake db:migrate table does not exist

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

We have various scripts that run daily generate various reports for our clients in MYSQL database. In order to generate those report  scripts use staging aka tmp tables to store data before all data joined into final report. The staging/tmp tables are dropped by scripts as soon as they no longer need it. While reporting scripts are running we may perform daily release that may include changes to whose deployment by rails db:migrate task. When it happens that deployment and report generation script happen to execute simultaneously we get the following error:  "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'novo.tmp_instrep_announ_23_336_15852014988512075' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `tmp_instrep_announ_23_336_15852014988512075`". We have no control when report is triggered by end user.

IS there way to make rake db:migrate script to ignore tmp tables ?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Why is `db:migrate` trying to drop the table in the first place? Is there a migration that says to do so?

Comment: Are these temporary tables being created with a migration? If so then that's your problem right there. Migrations where not intended for this purpose.

Comment: You can use `rails db:schema:load` instead of migrating

Comment: @Gotey still won't fix the issue if you want to use migrations to create new tables or alter exisiting tables.